# Little database problem

Tags: jquery, database, codeigniter, label

Hi am working on a seat reservation project. I am making this project in code_igniter. Now I have a little problem with sending the seat label through the database. In my project there is a little JQuery part. When I check a checkbox, the name will be placed on a label. But when I send it to the database it always returns 0 ???

This is my jquery function.

```
      $('[name=check]').each(function(i,d){
                    $(d).removeAttr('disabled');
                });
            }
                   $("#seatDiv").html($(this).val());
                 $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("input[name=check]").change(function() {
                    $("#seatDiv").html($(this).val());
                    })
                    });
```

My form

```
   echo form_open('user/register');
        $username = array(
           'name'       =>  'reg_username',
            'id'        =>  'reg_username',
            'value'     =>  set_value('reg_username')
        );
           $email = array(
           'name'       =>  'reg_email',
            'id'        =>  'reg_email',
            'value'     =>  set_value('reg_email')
        );
            $gsmnummer = array(
           'name'       =>  'reg_gsmnummer',
            'id'        =>  'reg_gsmnummer',
            'value'     =>  set_value('reg_gsmnummer')
        );
            $zitplaats = array(
           'name'       =>  'reg_zitplaats',
            'id'        =>  'reg_zitplaats',
            'value'     =>  '$id'
        );
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label> Naam </label></td>
           <td> <div> <?php echo form_input($username); ?></div></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>e-mail </label></td>
            <td><div> <?php echo form_input($email); ?></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label> gsm-nummer </label></td>
            <td><div> <?php echo form_input ($gsmnummer); ?> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>zitplaats</label></td>

            <td><div id="seatDiv" > <?php echo form_label($id='seatDiv'); ?> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
       <td> <?php echo form_submit(array('name'=> 'verzend','value' => 'verzend')); ?> </td>

      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

And my user_model

```
class User_model extends Model{
function User_model() {
    parent :: Model() ;
}
function register_user($username, $email, $gsmnummer, $zitplaats){

    $query_str ="INSERT INTO tbl_reservering (username,gsmnummer,email,zitplaats)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $this->db->query($query_str,array($username,$email,$gsmnummer,$zitplaats));
}
```

}

Hope anyone can help me!

thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can access the value of a label in this manner - there's no "POST" data from it. Can't you store the result in a textbox and style it to look like a label?

Comment: Which name are you talking about? Is the user name empty when you want to insert it to the database? Maybe I'm missing something but there is no element `input[name=check]` in your code. And `form_label($id='seatDiv');` looks wrong.

Comment: no everything is insert correctly into the db. Only the the value of "zitplaats". It always returns zero. Also if i change the label into a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$zitplaats = array(
           'name'       =>  'reg_zitplaats',
            'id'        =>  'reg_zitplaats',
            'value'     =>  '$id'
        );
```

Variables aren't parsed when they are in single quotes.

and where is `$id` being set from.

```
<tr>
            <td><label>zitplaats</label></td>

            <td><div id="seatDiv" > <?php echo form_label($id='seatDiv'); ?> </div></td>
```

you also aren't even using `$zitplaats` in your code.

I'm not sure what `form_label($id='seatDiv')` is doing either, doesn't look right to me.

What's the output?

Comment: The ouput in the database is a 0 for zitplaats. And I don't know what the value of $zitplaats is. I was just trying different things.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a hidden input that contains the value you want to pass to the controller (and ultimately the model). Ensure that your controller is set up to retrieve 'reg_zitplaats'.

Your jQuery should look something like this (I've made some modifications to your original post as it was doing some really strange stuff):

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name=check]').removeAttr('disabled'); // not sure why the checkbox is disabled to start off with

  $('input[name=check]').change(function() {
    $('#seatDiv').html($(this).val());
    $('#reg_zitplaats').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Then, your html can be as so (notice the hidden input):

```
<?php 
echo form_open('user/register');
$username = array(
  'name' => 'reg_username',
  'id' =>  'reg_username',
  'value' =>  set_value('reg_username')
);

$email = array(
  'name' => 'reg_email',
  'id' => 'reg_email',
  'value' => set_value('reg_email')
);

$gsmnummer = array(
  'name' => 'reg_gsmnummer',
  'id' => 'reg_gsmnummer',
  'value' => set_value('reg_gsmnummer')
);

$zitplaats = array(
  'name' => 'reg_zitplaats',
  'id' => 'reg_zitplaats',
  'value' => $id
);
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Naam</label></td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <?php echo form_input($username); ?>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>e-mail </label></td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <?php echo form_input($email); ?>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>gsm-nummer</label></td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <?php echo form_input($gsmnummer); ?>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>zitplaats</label></td>
    <td>
      <?php echo form_hidden($zitplaats); ?>
      <div id="seatDiv" > 
        <?php echo form_label($id='seatDiv'); ?>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo form_submit(array('name'=> 'verzend','value' => 'verzend')); ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Try this out and let us know how you go.